# ASP classic - Microsoft SQL and multiple where clauses on an UPDATE

Tags: sql, asp-classic, where-clause

I have the following string but it seems to not like it:

```
"UPDATE 
   table 
      SET a = '', b = '34' 
   WHERE id = '1000001'; 
      SET a = '1111', b = '11' 
   WHERE id = '100210'; 
      SET a = '', b = '2' 
   WHERE id = '8002059';"
```

In my asp classic code that string is on one line.. Is this the correct way of doing multiple update/where statements?

Answer (score 0):

It will like this better (3 statements).

```
UPDATE table SET a = '', b = '34' WHERE id = '1000001'; 

UPDATE table SET a = '1111', b = '11' WHERE id = '100210'; 

UPDATE table SET a = '', b = '2' WHERE id = '8002059';
```

Alternatively you can use two CASE statements in your SETs.  It won't be as readable but will run slightly more quickly having 1 database round trip rather than 3 if this is a 1-off situation where you frequently need exactly 3 conditional updates performed (unlikely).

```
UPDATE table SET 

a = CASE id WHEN '1000001' THEN '' WHEN '100210' THEN '1111' WHEN '8002059' THEN '' ELSE a END, 

b = CASE id WHEN '1000001' THEN '34' WHEN '100210' THEN '11' WHEN '8002059' THEN '2' ELSE b END

WHERE id IN ('1000001', '100210', '8002059');
```

Comment: so you mean in my string, also put the update table part in too?

Comment: you should change `table` to `[table]`

Comment: aghh generating this string in an asp classic for loop sucks haha. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will give you an error.

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'.
```

And you can't use multiple where in [UPDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement.

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE 
   [table]
   set a =
   ( case when id IN ( '1000001', '8002059') then  '' 
          when id = '100210' then '1111'
     end    
   ),
   b =  
   ( case when id = '1000001' then '34' 
          when id = '100210' then '11'
          when id = '8002059' then '2'
     end    
   )
   where id in ('1000001', '100210', '8002059');
```